# SQL case when to count null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query, data looks like this:

Data:

| ID | name | date_completed | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sydney | 2021-01-01 | A |
| 2 | Melbourne | 2021-01-5 | A |
| 3 | Sydney | 2021-01-10 | B |
| 4 | Sydney | 2021-02-01 | A |
| 5 | Melbourne | 2021-02-07 | A |
| 6 | Melbourne | 2021-02-13 | A |

My query:

```
SELECT name
         , '01-01-21' AS Date
         , (case
                when version = 'A' then 'A'
                when version = 'B' then 'B'
        end)          AS 'Type'
         , (case
                when version = 'A' then count(ID)
                when version = 'B' then count(ID)
        end)          AS 'Count'
    FROM table
    WHERE date_completed between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
    GROUP BY name, version

    UNION

SELECT name
         , '01-02-21' AS Date
         , (case
                when version = 'A' then 'A'
                when version = 'B' then 'B'
        end)          AS 'Type'
         , (case
                when version = 'A' then count(ID)
                when version = 'B' then count(ID)
        end)          AS 'Count'
    FROM table
    WHERE date_completed between '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-28'
    GROUP BY name, version
```

Output:

| name | date | Type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sydney | 01-01-21 | A | 1 |
| Melbourne | 01-01-21 | A | 1 |
| Sydney | 01-01-21 | B | 1 |
| Sydney | 01-02-21 | A | 1 |
| Melbourne | 01-02-21 | A | 2 |

The issue I'm facing is that because version A/B doesn't exist for some months it will not show a row with count = 0

I'm trying to create an output like this:

| name | date | Type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sydney | 01-01-21 | A | 1 |
| Melbourne | 01-01-21 | A | 1 |
| Sydney | 01-01-21 | B | 1 |
| Melbourne | 01-01-21 | B | 0 |
| Sydney | 01-02-21 | A | 1 |
| Melbourne | 01-02-21 | A | 2 |
| Sydney | 01-02-21 | B | 0 |
| Melbourne | 01-02-21 | B | 0 |

Is this something that can be done without having to create a separate table with name, date & type and using LEFT JOIN between the two tables?

Also is there a better way of dealing with querying data within a specific month without having to union multiple select statements?

Thanks

Comment: More than 20 years after Y2K - NEVER use 2-digit years.  `'01-01-21' AS Date` You might think this is a date but to the database engine it is a string. Don't assume your choice of formatting will always be interpreted according to your rules. Use a format that can always be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all combination of `name` - `month` - `version` and then `left join` to your table and then perform the `count()`

If you have individual table of name, version, you may use that instead of finding the distinct value from the table (`select distinct name from tbl`)

```
with 
name_mth_ver as
(
    select name, mth_st, mth_en, version
    from
    (
        select distinct name
        from   tbl
    ) n
    cross join
    (
         select distinct
                mth_st = convert(date, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, date_completed), 0)),
                mth_en = convert(date, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, date_completed) + 1, -1))
         from   tbl
    ) m
    cross join
    (
        select distinct version
        from   tbl
    ) v
)
select n.name
       , n.mth_st AS [Date]
       , n.version AS [Type]
       , count(t.ID) AS [Count]
from   name_mth_ver n
       left join tbl t on  n.name    = t.name
                       and n.mth_st <= t.date_completed
                       and n.mth_en >= t.date_completed
                       and n.version = t.version
group by n.name, n.mth_st, n.version
```